# Swing - Changing the Windows Theme resets custom border, insets and backgrounds

Tags: java, windows, swing, themes, look-and-feel

When changing the windows theme / design, the UI reacts to those changes, resetting custom component backgrounds, borders and insets.

For example we have some `JScrollPane`s, where we have set the `Border` to `null`. Every `JScrollPane`s `Border` gets reset to its custom value, which is something non-`null`.

Setting the given key via `UIManager.put(...)` doesn't show any effect either, since the `UIManager` values aren't applied on such resets.

Is there any way around those automatic resets, besides writing a custom L&F, which would take way too long for such minimal benefits, is there any way to solve this problem?

Some runtime information (In case someone wants to know):

- OS: Windows 10 64-Bit
- JDK: 8u172 64-Bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reseting of Look-n-Feel provides the global reset of all borders, colors, fonts, etc. Especially when they reset to `null`. So if you want to protect your borders from this reset you need to replace:

```
myComponent.setBorder(null);
```

to

```
myComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. Not only did we set things to `null`, we also used Colors retrieved by `UIManager.get(...)`. Since those were `UIRessource`s, they got replaced as well. In order to fix that problem, we had to create local copies of those `Color`s.